# display ajax information under input field

Tags: php, ajax

I tried to develop an ajax to display some information.
My ajax works fine but it do not display the information under the input field.
Do you have any idea to resolve that ?

thank you.

```
     $content .= HTML::inputField('suppliers_id', $suppliers_id . ' ' . $suppliers_name, 'id="ajax_suppliers_id" list="supplier_list" class="form-control"', null, null, null);
      $content .= '<datalist id="supplier_list"></datalist>';
      $suppliers_ajax = this->link('ajax/suppliers.php');



<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    // Add a keyup event listener to our input element
    document.getElementById('ajax_suppliers_id').addEventListener("keyup", function(event){hinter(event)});
    // create one global XHR object
    // so we can abort old requests when a new one is make
    window.hinterXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
});

// Autocomplete for form
function hinter(event) {
    var input = event.target;
    var ajax_suppliers_id = document.getElementById('ajax_suppliers_id');
    // minimum number of characters before we start to generate suggestions
    var min_characters = 0;

    if (!isNaN(input.value) || input.value.length < min_characters ) {
        return;
    } else {
        window.hinterXHR.abort();
        window.hinterXHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var response = JSON.parse( this.responseText );
                ajax_suppliers_id.innerHTML = "";

                response.forEach(function(item) {
                    // Create a new <option> element.
                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.value = item;
                    ajax_suppliers_id.appendChild(option);
                });
            }
        };
        window.hinterXHR.open("GET", "{$suppliers_ajax}?q=" + input.value, true);
        window.hinterXHR.send()
    }
}
</script>
```

my ajax request called across the input field, I use to display information:

```
   if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
    $terms = HTML::sanitize(strtolower($_GET['q']));

    $Qcheck = $this->Db->prepare('select distinct suppliers_id as id,
                                                         suppliers_name as name
                                       from :table_suppliers
                                       where suppliers_name LIKE :terms
                                       limit 10;
                                      ');
    $Qcheck->bindValue(':terms', '%' . $terms . '%');
    $Qcheck->execute();

    $list = $Qcheck->rowCount();

    if ($list > 0) {
      $array = [];
      
      while ($value = $Qcheck->fetch()) {
        $array[] = $value;
      }
      
# JSON-encode the response
      $json_response = json_encode($array); //Return the JSON Array

# Return the response
      echo $json_response;
    }
```

example of response I can see on sa keywords:

```
[{"id":"3","name":"Samsug"}]
```

Comment: can you show output of `response` ?

Comment: This is a good time to use your browser's debugging tools.  Are there any errors at all in the console?  Is the response from the AJAX request what you expect?  What is the value of the `response` variable at runtime?  Does the `forEach()` iterate at all?  What is the value of `item` in that iteration?  What specifically happens?

Comment: I updated.  see above . tk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending new options inside input but you need to append it inside `datalist` .Also ,  `option.value = item.name` will give you result has `[Object object]` that's why you need to specify field i.e : `id ,name` to access same elements . i.e : `item.name` .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var ajax_suppliers_id = document.getElementById('supplier_list');//daatlist id 
var response = [{
  "id": "3",
  "name": "Samsug"
},{
  "id": "3",
  "name": "Samsug1"
},{
  "id": "3",
  "name": "Samsug2"
}];
ajax_suppliers_id.innerHTML = "";
response.forEach(function(item) {
  // Create a new <option> element.
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.value = item.name;//get name 
  ajax_suppliers_id.appendChild(option);
});
```

```html
<input list="supplier_list" class="form-control" id="ajax_suppliers_id">
<datalist id="supplier_list"></datalist>
```

Comment: Ok tk for the solution but I need to pass also the suppliers_id in hidden field to save the supplier name.Currently it's only the supplier_name

Comment: Hi where is that `hidden field` ? can you elaborate ?